# bash, mirroring of multiple directories (hard linking)

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, cron

I have 5 FTP users that upload files (and subdirectories) in their home directory, i need to mirror theese directories beetween them and with a "master" directory (accessible from a 6th user). Files can contain spaces or others special caracters.
All the files are in the same filesystem, and i want to use hard link because i don't want to waste 5 time the space of a single file.

I tried with find but i cannot handle spaces in it.

Comment: Re "I tried with find but i cannot handle spaces in it.": You were doing it the wrong way, then. Post the command that you tried.

Answer (score -1):

Hardlink the directory

```
 ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY     (3rd form)
```

Spaces should be processed using `"name with space"` or `name\ with\ space` I guess.

Comment: Directories cannot be hardlinked on any modern filesystem without resorting to black magic.

Comment: In my system it's not possible to hard-link one directory... Directories can only be soft-linked.